# type casting void pointer to struct type

Tags: c, arrays, struct

How do I type cast a void pointer to a struct array?  Here is my code:

```
typedef struct{
    int   a;
    double b;
} myStruct;

void Func1(void * Array1);

int main(){
    myStruct S1[5];

    S1[0].a = 1;
    S1[0].b = 2.3;

    S1[1].a = 2;
    S1[1].b = 3.4;

    Func1(S1);

    return 0;
}

void Func1(void * Array1){
    myStruct S2[5];

    S2[0] = (myStruct *)Array1[0];
}
```

I get compile errors in `Func1` for assigning `S2[0]`.  How do I typecast the `Array1` correctly?

Comment: main question, why do you declare Func1 as void* in the first place? What errors do you get? Tried to ((myStruct *)Array1)[0]?

Comment: A pointer is not an array, and neither one is the element type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[]` operator has a higher precedence that a `(cast)` operator. Thus you have to use additional parenthesis:

```
 S2[0] = ((myStruct *)Array1)[0];
```

or use a pointer:

```
myStruct* a = Array1 ;
S2[0] = a[0];
```

Comment: or the dereference-operator instead.